# Is there a way to return a function as false and still execute code untill it reverts, eq: function owner() { owner = 0x0; revert(); }

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

So putting revert() or throw at the end of the function simply prevents any code from executing, I am looking for a clever way to escape this be it with external call, delegatecall or anything, so:

```
function thiss()
{
owner = 0x0...;
throw; //gives error, no changes whatsoever - what I want is to see changes and then "throw"...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `event`. You can emit an event and then return the function. You can know the error by looking at `logs` field in the transaction receipt.

```js
event ErrorLog(string msg);

function this() public {
    Owner = 0x583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225;
    emit ErrorLog("Error in function this");
    return;
}
```

Comment: interesting but can event execute code? That is: do anything other than simple logging? thanks and again this is interesting i admit my understanding of events is the most limited with regards to solidity.